# Set table name dynamically when importing into access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have the below code which links Excel files to Access 2016. However, it creates the table names copying from the file name. How do I edit the code to copy the sheet names and create tables with those names.

Like A.xls has sheet "A" and B.xlsm has sheet "B". Currently, it creates A.xls as table name and not A.

```
   Option Compare Database

   Option Explicit

   'code will link to excel and pull site files into access tables

   'Setting the path for the directory

    Sub LinkExcel()
    Dim iFile As String 'Filename
    Dim iFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

    Dim iPath As String

    iPath = "C:\Users\mchattopad004\Documents\Files\" 'Directory Path

   'Loop through the folder & build file list
    iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xls")
    While iFile <> ""
    'add files to the list
    intFile = intFile + 1
    ReDim Preserve iFileList(1 To intFile)
    iFileList(intFile) = iFile
    iFile = Dir()
    Wend

   'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
    End If

   'cycle through the list of files & link to Access
   For intFile = 1 To UBound(iFileList)
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
   iFileList(intFile), iPath & iFileList(intFile), True 
   Next

   MsgBox UBound(iFileList) & " Files were Linked"

  End Sub
```

Comment: The third optional parameter of the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is the table name. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access

Comment: I tried removing the table name parameter but the code would throw me error saying " Table Name argument required".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line where you are specifying the table name

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
iFileList(intFile), iPath & iFileList(intFile), True 'Set your range here.
```

The 3rd argument is the TableName argument, so change it to this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
Replace(Replace(iFileList(intFile), ".xlsm", ""), ".xls", ""), _
iPath & iFileList(intFile), True
```

That should remove the extension.

Comment: This still adds the extensions of the files.

Comment: What about `.xlsm`? :)

Comment: OP says it's adding `.xls` - not `.xlsm` - But that would be a matter of just adding another `Replace`.

Comment: I see no `.xlsm` but i'll add it in just for you since it wont hurt anything.

Comment: Good man. Just for reference "...Like A.xls has sheet "A" and B.xlsm has sheet "B"..." :)

Comment: Ah I see it now, but since this line of code `iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xls")` ignores all `xlsm` files, it's a pointless addition.

Comment: Ah I see it now, but since this line of code `iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.xls")` ignores all xlsm files, it's a pointless addition. - This adds the .xlsm files too since I am linking that file but @braX the latest code works and removes the extensions.